# Merging multiple github user accounts and transfer commits

Tags: github

I have two GitHub accounts. One from my work and my personal one, and i wanna merge these two.

I already read this doc: [Merging multiple user accounts](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/transferring-a-repository)

But i still remain with two doubt:

1. After i add the same e-mail to my personal account. All my collaboration in repos will be transfered too?
2. the repos that my work account was a colaborator, my personal account will get the permision too?

Comment: If you have a question about GitHub, you should solve it [there](https://support.github.com/)

Comment: Thanks! I submitted a ticket, and i will be back with the results!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They answered my ticket:

> Contributions are linked to your email address, so adding your
> existing email to your new account will transfer these over.
>
> However collaboration and permissions in other repos is attached to
> the account itself, not the email, so you will need to request to be
> added as a collaborator again for any repos you currently collaborate
> on.
>
> Likewise, if you are a member of an organisation, you'll need to be
> added to that organisation again and any teams you were a member of.

Answer (score 0):

Commits are associated to your email: after transferring all the repos etc. and deleting your account, you need to add the previous email address (from the deleted account) to the new account in your account settings. The commit history will now be linked to your new account.